# Experiment design useful when objects change / will be replaced in each trial run?

Tags: r, experiment-design, quality-control, replicability

I want to perform some studies on how material thickness, type of material, humidity and temperature influence tensile strength.
While I was thinking about useful designs I was wondering whether a certain design makes sense at all as I'll use for each investigation a new object.

Let's say a design experiment suggests for the first runs:

```
   Temperature humidity thickness
1  20 °C       50 %     1 cm
2  40 °C       30 %     2 cm
3  10 °C       30 %     1 cm
...
```

and so on.. so for each run I would use new objects and thus I would not keep the same object or material or device throughout the entire experiment.
Would I have to consider this somehow in a DoE?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the object changes from one run to the other is not an issue. As usual, the object-to-object variability will influence your inference. If the objects come by batches, then you can use blocking. In any case, DoE methodology applies here.

Comment: Thank you! When the objects will be replaced in each run, I guess DoE will improve the experiment only w.r.t. to the experimental measurement devices. But then I wonder in which way? Temperature and humidity can be set technically very precisely so how would DoE change anything?

Comment: It is quite usual to replace objects in each run. The advantages of the DoE methodology depends on which criteria were used to pick a particular DoE. E.g. you might want to estimate interaction effects, or you might want to minimize the standard errors. In any case, the DoE methodology is a way to formalize your problem and to provide you with a set of fit-for-purpose experiments to solve it. But again, the fact that the object changes from one run to the other is not an issue, just like multiple patients are recruited in a clinical trial.

Comment: thanks again and true that! You're right, though I'm tryin' to understand DoE. E.g., when I wouldn't do randomization, what would I loose?

Comment: You would likely loose run-to-run independence

Comment: what does this mean statistically? or even better: for my measurements?

Comment: Just be sure to randomize!